# How to print the sum of even number in c using do-while loop

Tags: c

I have created the following program, but i cannot find a way to print the sum of all the even numbers. This program is only giving me all even numbers from 2 to 30. How can i print the sum of all even numbers from 2 to 30 in this program??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

    int counter = 0,sum;

    do{
        if(counter % 2 == 0){
            printf("%d\n", counter += 2);
        }
    } while (counter <= 30);

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We can help you with something you don't understand, but “write my program for me” isn't a question. What part are you having trouble with? Have you tried to compute the sum?

Comment: This is clearly a homework question: people of SO, please don't answer homework questions with working code.  A much better answer here would be to say, "Mentally stepping through your code, when will `printf()` get run?  And when will `getch()` get run?  When is `counter` 'ready' to be printed?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you set the sum variable to the initial value of 0. Then each time you add 2 to the counter, you add the counter to sum. It's very simple to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int counter = 0, sum = 0;

   do{
        if(counter != 0){//Is not necessary if you start out with counter = 2.
            printf("%d\n", counter);
            sum += counter;
        }
    } while ((counter += 2) <= 30);
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is your answer..

```
int main() {

int counter = 0,sum=0;

do{
    if(counter % 2 == 0){
                sum += counter;
                }

    } while (counter <= 30);
    printf("Sum of even number:=%d", sum);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Funny! This will certainly get the OP an A+ on their homework!